# How do I know my Facebook ID - I have two?? A Long "1015443**********" and short "6045*****" one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the tool (SimpleSAMLphp) to sign in to Facebook. The attributes I have indicate my Facebook UID is "1015443**********", but when I use tools online (http://findmyfbid.com) I'm seeing a shorter "6045*****" number. I just need to ensure I'm using an ID that will not change for this user (as I understand that users can change their email in Facebook). Ideally I'd rather use the long number as that's what I have currently from the authentication tool.

Comment: Maybe `id` vs `third_party_id`? Related info: [Generate Facebook user picture using third_party_id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466401/generate-facebook-user-picture-using-third-party-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID you get with findmyfbid.com is your "real" ID, but they are doing something that is not allowed on Facebook: Scraping. Because you can only get your "real" ID from the source code of your profile page.

The ID you get in Apps is an "App Scoped ID", and it´s the only ID you get in Apps. It´s different per App. Check out the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0